# Passing parameters from c++ to c# as call back

Tags: c#, c++, callback, interop, unsigned-integer

I have a c++ and c# application talking to each other.

The way I have set things up is as follows:

the c++ project is referred to in the c# project as follows

[image]

Now it does various things which are not something related to this question.

The requirement is, c# will call c++ and then c++ will do a callback event of c#. Here is how I have registered a call back in C#:

```
                Add_CB_onVideoMediaReceived(OnVideoMediaReceived);
```

In c++, I have the following which is adding a callback to events

```
event OnVideoMediaReceived^ event_onVideoMediaReceived;

virtual void Add_CB_onVideoMediaReceived(OnVideoMediaReceived^ cb)
        {
            event_onVideoMediaReceived += cb;
        }
```

Now in c++, I am calling this method where I have to trigger a call back to c#

```
unsigned int height = data->GetStreamHeight();
    unsigned int width = data->GetStreamWidth();
    unsigned int bufferLength = data->GetBufferLen();

    if (CMeetingRecordingControllerDotNetWrap::Instance)
    {
        if (data)
            CMeetingRecordingControllerDotNetWrap::Instance->_VideoMediaReceived(
                height,
                width,
                //data->GetStreamHeight(),
                bufferLength);
                //data->GetBuffer());
    }


void CMeetingRecordingControllerDotNetWrap::_VideoMediaReceived(unsigned int userId, unsigned int screenHeight,unsigned int screenWidth) {
        event_onVideoMediaReceived(userId, screenHeight,screenWidth);
    }
```

That basically triggers the c# event, however, I get the correct value in the only first argument. For the rest of the argument, if for example, the value that I pass is 300 as an integer, I get a very long number in c# like 12333445444 instead of 300.

This is my c# receiver code is

```
  private void OnVideoMediaReceived(UInt32 userId, UInt32 screenHeight, UInt32 screenWidth)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username changed: user ID" + userId.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/3a55661e-5d6f-4e29-b2b6-99fa807890a2/call-c-methods-from-c-application?forum=vcgeneral&force_isolation=true

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "from C++" do you mean strictly *managed* C++ (i.e. C++/CLI)?  Obviously I see some C++/CLI in there but are you also trying to have *unmanaged* C++ call your C++/CLI which will then call up to C#?